# C++ do while loop keeps going after EOF

Tags: c++

I have a question about file I/O.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    using namespace std;
    string InputFileName="", temp=""; //File Name entered on command line

    int Factor1=0, Factor2=0, MaxNum=0;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "No File Name Specified\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //InputFileName = argv[1]; //Get File Name from command line arguments array
        ifstream inf (argv[1]); //open file for reading

        if(!inf) //check for errors opening file, print message and exit program with error
        {

            cerr << " Error opening input file\n"; 
            return 1;
        }


        do
        {
            inf >> Factor1;
            inf >> Factor2;
            inf >> MaxNum;
            cout << "Factor 1: " << Factor1 << " Factor 2: " << Factor2 << " Maximum Number: " << MaxNum << "\n";
        }while(inf);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

input file contains:

```
3 5 10
2 7 15
```

output is:

```
Factor 1: 3 Factor 2: 5 Maximum Number: 10
Factor 1: 2 Factor 2: 7 Maximum Number: 15
Factor 1: 2 Factor 2: 7 Maximum Number: 15
```

This is not homework.  It has been 20 years since I took a C++ class.  I am trying to brush up on C++.  I have spent most of my career working in Visual Basic.  My question is why does the while loop not catch the EOF and exit before it outputs the 3rd line and how do I fix it, or am I going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Your indentation is very misleading.

Comment: the indentation is a result of copying it over to the stackoverflow editor, I apologize.

Comment: @WilliamMichaelVondran: You can correct it before hitting "Submit", though.

Comment: It was a honest mistake I checked but missed it.  It is fixed now.

Comment: Perhaps it is a curse of operator overloading that it makes it harder to teach the checking of return values, since it hides function calls grammatically. That said, object orientation moves "success of function call" to "validity of the state object", so perhaps the idioms need to adapt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *cannot* predict whether I/O will succeed. You *must* check the return value:

```
while (inf >> Factor1 >> Factor2 >> MaxNum)   // checks the value of "inf", i.e.
{                                             // whether the input succeeded
    cout << "Factor 1: " << Factor1
         << " Factor 2: " << Factor2
         << " Maximum Number: " << MaxNum << "\n";
}
```

Your original code recklessly assumes that the input succeeded without checking, continued to *consume* the input, and only much later went back to ask, "oh by the way, was any of that actually legit?"